# Gasoline-Powered Supersoldiers

Tags: science-based, biology, soldiers

According to our current understanding of biology and chemistry, could genetically engineered supersoldiers that digest hydrocarbons (such as those found in gasoline) feasibly be created within a world set in the near future (say the next 20 years)?

I imagine this as the supersoldiers having digestive enzymes that can break down hydrocarbons into usable metabolites, as well as an altered digestive tract that is resistant to its solvent properties, but I am sure there are other factors I am not considering.

Tactically, I imagine the incentive for gasoline-powered supersoldiers to be that they can (at least temporarily) live off a highly energy-dense food source, which also happens to be the same fuel that powers ground vehicles, greatly simplifying logistics and perhaps allowing greater scavenging potential in urban environments. That said, the focus of this question is on the biochemistry of such soldiers, not their tactical viability.

Comment: Are you asking us to help you design gasoline-powered super soldiers for your imaginary world? If so, what's the specific problem you need help with? Because bringing the fantastic into the Real World isn't what we do here. See the [help/on-topic].

Comment: NATO military vehicles generally do not use gasoline. Most ground and air vehicles are designed to use F-34 diesel (or a substitute), with various additives for stability, inhibiting corrosion, changing the freezing point, etc.

Comment: It seems a contradiction that a society would have vast sums available to breed platoons/companies/battalions of supersoldiers, but then be so parsimonious as to require these elite weapons to squander their valuable time scavenging for sustenance -- or so incompetent as to let them be cut off from their regular-food (and water and ammunition) supply. That's how you lose a war.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/214426/30492

Comment: Scavenging for gasoline may become rather difficult on the 20 year timeframe. Unleaded? Sure, there's a couple cans in the last aisle, next to the VHS tapes and floppy disks.

Comment: @user_1818839 because electric vehicles will become more prevalent?

Comment: If gasoline-powered is the goal, I think the giant-robot approach is going to be easier than the replace-a-billion-years-of-evolution-of-the-digestive-system approach:  https://dailyturismo.com/15-ton-2-story-tall-gasoline-powered/

Comment: @JeremyFriesner well, the goal is gasoline powered soldiers, since I kind of like the bio-dieselpunk-ish aesthetic, rather than mechs

Comment: Dang nabit. It's funny when that hammer kicks in and when it doesn't. It's not consistent. MS, I was expecting four other people to think about the link @L.Dutch posted, which makes this question look very much like a duplicate. Do me a favor, if you can explain why that previous question doesn't answer yours, I'll be happy to retract the vote to reopen.

Comment: @JBH as stated, the answers to that question arguably do answer my own, although they don't go into much more detail than "yes, it's possible" as they largely focus on environmental and evolutionary factors. I would be happy to refine my question to focus more on what (engineered) adaptations would be required to allow a diesel guzzling soldier, but I'm not sure whether that would violate the convention of not allowing edits to make existing answers invalid. Perhaps I should simply post a new, differently focused question?

Comment: @MS You seriously want us to explain the medical, genetic, and pharmaceutical procedures to do this? Assuming there's a human being on earth who could provide that (and I have my doubts...), they would be [running for the patent office, not explaining it here.](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8273/40609) This site isn't physics-lite. Asking how to make the fantastic real is a poor fit for this Stack.

Comment: @L.Dutch I'll follow your advice on this one. If you think it's reasonable (or even rational) to ask *for the details* about how to modify the human body to run on gasoline and that said details exclude the question you linked as a duplicate, I'll retract my vote.

Comment: @JBH as far as I can tell, "making the fantastic real" is a largely meaningless phrase you throw around when you dislike a question. By it's very definition, a fictional concept is fictional, and any world implementing such a world is necessarily fictional. Finding rationalizations and explanations for fictional concepts (or real concepts implemented in fictional worlds) is literally what this stack exists for. Indeed, I am not not at all sure how you interpret "what adaptations to be required" to mean "everything surrounding the topic must be described in perfect and exact detail".

Comment: @JBH My comment never once mentions "medical, genetic, and pharmaceutical procedures". As always, it seems you have assumed the worst and overreacted. The science-based tag exists for a reason, which is "for questions that require plausible (better than suspension-of-disbelief) answers based on Real World science that are not necessarily constrained to the known limits of Real World science".

Comment: `although they don't go into much more detail than "yes, it's possible"` Please [edit] your post to explain ***exactly*** what you're expecting that answers to the previous question do not provide and I'll revoke my close. By all means, prove to me that you're not trying to make your fiction factual.

Answer (score 4):

It's not reasonable to expect genetic engineering to produce humans that can digest hydrocarbons in the next 20 years. Instead of just swapping out one gene for another, we would need to develop the genetics to enable this ability -- with time for only the first generation to reach adulthood.

But if you want to wave your hands around this, you could genetically engineer a microorganism that digests hydrocarbons and excretes chemicals that are usable and helpful to your supersoldiers. These microorganisms are also engineered to live directly within the gut of your supersoldiers. Maybe this has some interesting side-effects, like your supersoldiers farting out clouds of exhaust. Nobody wants to march behind the diesel drinkers. They love to send out a thick, black cloud of noxious gas before racing off with the company's flag in tow.

More reasonable is to change the fuel that vehicles are using. In the name of sustainability, all vehicles run on a form of ethanol in 20 years. This ethanol is perfectly digestible for humans as well. Your supersoldiers are designed to drink huge amounts of ethanol, use it efficiently as an energy source, and not get drunk. Or maybe when they're drunk, they just get fearless and extra strong.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Regarding your first paragraph, I was under the impression (although I may be entirely incorrect) that we already have the technology to apply gene therapies *in vivo*, i.e you could inject a fully grown person with a vial of 'let me drink petrol', and within X amount of time their body will restructure to allow such. Regarding your last paragraph, ethanol seems to have a lower energy density than butter, making it seem less viable as an energy source. Of course, it would still provide the advantage of having your soldiers and vehicles run on the same fuel source.

Comment: Although the microorganism workaround is a good idea, we could turn our soldiers into little gasoline ruminants

Comment: @MS - you can't completely replace someone's gastric system with genetic therapy.  The tissues and organs don't get replaced.

Comment: @jdunlop but the tissues and organs can be caused to express new proteins, can they not?

Comment: @MS You need more than a few new proteins, you need whole metabolic pathways with proper coordination and control of expression - hundreds of genes. And that still doesn't restructure the digestive system that developed before birth.

Comment: What Cloudberry said.  Plus, gasoline (even purified of other more toxic hydrocarbons) is _systemically_ toxic, and volatile.  So even if your stomach can magically handle it, your lungs are going to start having to deal with gasoline vapours.  So your entire body needs to be reconfigured to process something that actively destroys things like red cells on contact.

Comment: @MS I wouldn't worry too much about the energy density of ethanol. Humans are pretty good at getting more calories than they need in a very short time. And watching an enemy supersoldier guzzle gallons of biofuel would be intimidating in its own right